# How to add icon_date and icon_time?

Tags: abap

How do I add `icon_date` and `icon_time` like in the transaction `SM37` (selection screen in block job start condition)

I am trying this

```
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK blk_1 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 1(8) G_DATE FOR FIELD p_sdate .
    SELECTION-SCREEN POSITION 25.
    PARAMETERS: p_sdate      TYPE sy-datum.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK blk_1.

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    INITIALIZATION.
     CONCATENATE TEXT-003 ICON_TIME INTO G_TIME
                    SEPARATED BY SPACE.                    " Text-003 = 'Date'

//////////////////////////////////////////////
Output => To @1T@
```

Comment: You use Text-001 in blk_1 and save the text in text-003. I this already your problem? If not, please show, how you use TEXT-003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code:

- Your comment variable is named `G_DATE`, but you're writing to `G_TIME`.
- You're trying to assemble the text for yourself instead of using the standard function.
- Your variable `G_DATE` is too short to store the complete formatted icon and text.

Try this:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT 1(60) g_date FOR FIELD p_sdate VISIBLE LENGTH 8.
SELECTION-SCREEN POSITION 25.
PARAMETERS p_sdate TYPE sy-datum.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.

INITIALIZATION.
  CALL FUNCTION 'ICON_CREATE'
    EXPORTING
      name       = 'ICON_DATE'
      text       = 'Date'
      info       = 'da date, man'
      add_stdinf = ' '
    IMPORTING
      result     = g_date.
```

[image]

Comment: How can i write some text before icon (with FOR FIELD p_sdate)?